# If statements inside where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below dataset

```
DNo     Quantity  Sites ID      Desc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
18050075    9       2   ADD6    Number of client reporting sites
18050075    9       2   ADD7    Annual Maintenance
18050075    9       2   ADD8    Ongoing Fees
18050075    1       2   ADD9    Employee Meeting (per day plus incurred expenses)
18050075    0       2   ADD10   Custom Data file Layouts
18050075    0       2   ADD11   Error Correction for more than 2% errors in a single
```

In a select statement inside a stored procedure, I only want to return ADD9, ADD10, ADD11 if quantity is greater than 0. Can someone please tell me how I can write an if statement inside where clause so I can only apply the condition to specific ID's

So my result set should be like below

```
 18050075   9   2   ADD6    Number of client reporting sites
 18050075   9   2   ADD7    Annual Maintenance
 18050075   9   2   ADD8    Ongoing Fees
 18050075   1   2   ADD9    Employee Meeting (per day plus incurred expenses)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the below? It relies on splitting your data into two separate queries and then appending.

```
select * -- this gets all data other than these ids
from your_data_table
where ID not in ('ADD9', 'ADD10', 'ADD11')

union all -- this joins everything toghether

select * -- this gets all requested data for these ids
from your_data_table
where ID in ('ADD9', 'ADD10', 'ADD11') and Quantity > 0
```

Comment: Great approach..I was doing another union at the end of main query so if using this style can I combine Union All with another union.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table where (ID in('ADD9','ADD10','ADD11') and Quantity > 0) or ID not in('ADD9','ADD10','ADD11')

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID NOT IN ('ADD9', 'ADD10', 'ADD11') OR Quantity > 0;
```

Comment: Not really.. I still want the other ID's but only want to filter these three id's based on quantity > 0 condition

Answer (score 0):

For your result set that you have provided as output

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE Quantity > 0
```

For your result set that you have mentioned in the description

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE ID IN ('ADD9', 'ADD10', 'ADD11') AND Quantity > 0
```

Note: You are actually asking for the two different output as you mentioned in description and given output so please decide one what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is to use nested CASE functions. e.g.:

```
select * 
from your_data_table
where 1 = (CASE WHEN ID IN ('ADD9', 'ADD10', 'ADD11') THEN CASE WHEN Quantity > 0 THEN 1 END ELSE 1 END)
```

The logic works like this:

```
IF ID IN ('ADD9', 'ADD10', 'ADD11')
THEN 
    IF Quantity > 0 
    THEN 
        Include It
    ELSE
        Exclude It
ELSE
    Include It
```